# Suppose that $A,B,C$ are events such that $A\cap\overline{C}=B\cap\overline{C}$. Show that $|P[A]−P[B]|\leq P[C]$.

Tags: probability

Suppose that $A, B, C$ are events such that $A \cap {\overline C} =  B \cap {\overline C}$. Show that $|P[ A] - P[ B]| \le P[ C]$.

My attempt:-

$
 A \cap \overline{ C} =  B \cap \overline{ C} 
\implies 
P[ A \cap \overline{ C}] = P[ B \cap \overline{ C}]
\implies
P[ A] + P[\overline{ C}] - P[ A \cup \overline{ C}] = P[ B] + P[\overline{ C}] - P[ B \cup \overline{ C}]
\implies 
P[ A] - P[ B] = P[ A\cup \overline{ C}] - P[ B \cup\overline{ C}]
$

and if this is correct, then I think I need to prove that:
$
|{P[ A\cup \overline{ C}] - P[ B \cup\overline{ C}]}| \le P[C]
$

Maybe ${ A\cup \overline{ C} -  B \cup\overline{ C}}$ is out to be rewritten in other form?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: show that $|P(A)-P(B)| = |P(D) - P(E)| \le P(D) + P(E)$, where $D = A\cap\overline B$ and $E = B\cap\overline A$. Then show that $D\cap E=\emptyset$ and $D\cup E\subset C$. A Venn diagram will help!

Comment: |P(D)-P(E)|=|2(P(A)-P(B))+P(E)-P(D)|, ==> P(D)-P(E)=-(2(P(A)-P(B))+P(E)-P(D)) ==> P(A)=P(B). This is one case to solve the absolute value equation; opposite signs sides. but it produce P(A)=P(B). The other case with equal sign sides yields the desired conclusion P(A)−P(B)=P(D)−P(E). 
Any elaboration please?

Comment: And this is how I arrived to the previous statement:
|P(D)-P(E)|=|P(AnB')-P(A'nB)|=|P(A)+P(B')-P(AuB')-P(A')-P(B)+p(A'uB)|=|P(A)+1-P(B)+P(E)-1+P(A)-1-P(B)+1-P(D)|=|2(P(A)-P(B))+P(E)-P(D)|

Comment: I reached the last part D∪E⊂C will continue tmw, thanks for your help!

Comment: Venn diagram indeed helped! Also using logic notations made thinking easier (needed a refreshment, only my first week doing math since long ago). Please comment on my answer below!!

Answer (score 0):

$P[A]=P[A\cap C]+P[A\cap\overline C] $ and  $P[B]=P[B\cap C]+P[B\cap\overline C] $, so $|P[A] - P[B]|=|P[A\cap C]-P[B\cap C]|$

So if we considered $P[A\cap C]-P[B\cap C] = P[\{x|x\in A \land x \in C \land x \notin B\}]$ and if there exists $x$ such that $x \in C \land (x\in B \lor x \notin A)$ then $P[A\cap C]-P[B\cap C] \lt P[C]$, otherwise $P[A\cap C]-P[B\cap C] = P[C]$.

And similary for  $P[B\cap C] - P[A\cap C]$.